# How to collect api the "CPU Ready" statistic for each VM on ESX on an OpenSolaris box

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-esx

I'm on an OpenSolaris box  and I want to monitor the VMs on an ESX box.
VMware has a remote tool kit in perl for linux and a remote esxtop for LINUX, but is there a way to collect ESX statistics on a non-LINUX box, in this case OpenSolaris x86?
I can use ssh, expect and esxtop but want to know if there is way to do this with a remote API? (I'd rather not use ssh and expect)